# Extract all strings between delimiters

Tags: python, file, find, extract

I coded a function that extracts strings between two delimiters. But in some files, these delimiters appears several times, so i want to extract all of them.
In my actual function it only extracts the first that it comes across and then exits.

How can I fix it?

```
def extraction_error_CF(file): 

    f=open(file,'r')
    file=f.read()
    f.close()
    start = file.find('Error validating') #1st delimiter
    end = file.find('</SPAN><BR>', start) # 2nd delimiter
    if start!=-1 and end!=-1:             #If these two delimiters are present...
        return(file[start:end])
    else:
        return""
```

Comment: use a proper html/xml parser for this

Comment: you can pass an extra argument to `find` which is the offset of the last found pattern, just add 1 you'll find all of them

Comment: Sorry, i 've just started to code i didn't understand your solution with the html/xml parser, and the second solution i added '1' to : file.find('Error validating',1) but it still find only the first one. Thanks

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre we cannot blindly assume the file's content is actually a full HTML document - for what we know it could as well be a log file with markup in some messages or whatever else containing markup with being a true HTML doc.

Comment: @Tom92 we cannot properly answer your question without having a representative sample of your file's content.

Comment: Yes bruno, it's a log file containing markup that's why i'm using find()

Comment: I finally found a solution, thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTML/XML you should totally use robust modules like [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/),
but if you really just want the content between two delimiters, you can use your same function, but adding the results to a list (for example) then you can just print it out

```python
def extraction_error_CF(file): 

    f=open(file,'r')
    file=f.read()
    f.close()

    # Patterns
    first = "Error validating"
    second = "</span><br>"

    # For all the matches
    results = []

    # Iterate the whole file
    start = file.find(first)
    end = file.find(second)
    while start != -1 and end != -1:
        # Add everything between the patterns
        # but not including the patterns
        results.append(file[start+len(first):end])
        # Removing the text that already passed
        file = file[end+len(second):]

        start = file.find(first)
        end = file.find(second)

    # Return the content of the list as a string
    if len(results) != 0:
        return "".join(r for r in results)
    else:
        return None

print(extraction_error_CF("test"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

def extraction_error_CF(file): # Get error from CF upload 
    f=open(file,'r')
    file=f.read()
    f.close()
    start = re.findall('Error validating(.*)</SPAN><BR>',file)
    if start != -1:
        return start
    else:
        return""
```

That's what i did and it's working well thanks all !